# WebRTC not creating IceCandidates for video

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webrtc, webrtc-android

On an Android app I am trying to make a `webRTC` connection.

When I am the callee I receive enough number of `IceCandidate`s for video and audio from the socket connection. When my `IceCandidate`s are created there are much fewer of them. Approximately 6 of them are created and they are all for audio.

From the log messages I see connection is successful and audio is going both ways and I manage to send my video to the caller as well however I can not receive the caller's video stream. I guess it is related to not being able to create enough `IceCandidate`s to send to socket connection. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is not ideal but the following solved my problem.

First of all it is OK to have fewer number of `IceCandidate` s. During creation of `IceCandidate` s on my side, `sdpMid` fields still don't contain video value -i receive both video and audio values for `sdpMid` key in `IceCandidate` s from socket connection-.

All I had to do was to touch my views again after the connection is set with the following methods.

I walked through these [here](https://github.com/vivek1794/webrtc-android-codelab/blob/master/Step-3/app/src/main/java/xyz/vivekc/webrtccodelab/MainActivity.java) and [here](https://vivekc.xyz/getting-started-with-webrtc-part-4-de72b58ab31e).

```
private void updateVideoViews(final boolean remoteVisible) {
    activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = localVideoView.getLayoutParams();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params2 = remoteVideoView.getLayoutParams();
        if (remoteVisible) {
            params.height = dpToPx(100);
            params.width = dpToPx(100);

            params2.height = dpToPx(100);
            params2.width = dpToPx(100);
        } else {
            params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }
        localVideoView.setLayoutParams(params);
        remoteVideoView.setLayoutParams(params2);
    });
}

public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}
```

Comment: Hii I have the same issue as urs and following the article that u suggested, I am also getting in logs about audio but not video and still, my issue has not solved the way u r saying .can u share me constrains and initial peer connection properties?